# How do I set the search path for a Python import?

Tags: python

I'm using Windows 10 with VS2015 and Python 3.4. I have created a module called `this.py`. Now I want to `import this.py`. That works OK if `this.py` is in the current folder. But I need `this.py` to be in a different folder which is used by all of my scripts.

I have tried a few approaches but none would find this.py. One approach was to set my Windows CMD PATH.

Can someone tell me how to set the search path for imports?

Comment: You should name your file something else, as `this` is already in the std lib. Try `import this` in the Python console, maybe you'll learn something new :)

Comment: You should read the Python documentation. They have a section on the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: My name is not really 'this.py'. It is 'vendr.py' ... 'this' was just a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path-here")
```

Then that directory will be searched when you import something (other than standard directories)

Edit: the path of the directory containing the imported file, not of the file